# Why is the Auth0 not throwing 403 with spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server when filtering by scope?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth, auth0

I have the following...

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/person", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class AuthController {
  @GetMapping("")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getPersonFromEmail(@RequestParam(name = "email") String email){ ... }
}
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    ...
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/person").hasAuthority("SCOPE_blahablah")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().cors()
                .and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

When I run but pass no token I get a 401. However, when I pass a token that doesn't have the proper scope I get a 200. I would expect to also get a 403. What am I missing?

With a little more digging it looks like the problem is the query params. Not sure how to acoomadate those...

```
~/tmp/user-profile >curl -v http://localhost:8080/person
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /person HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.85.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 403 
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=EFD9C400D91760FE8FA2119AC2EB382B; Path=/; HttpOnly
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 0
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 11 Jan 2023 21:45:16 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
~/tmp/user-profile >curl -v http://localhost:8080/person?email=...
zsh: no matches found: http://localhost:8080/person?email=... <-- This means it worked without checking
```

Comment: Adding @Configuration on the SecurityConfig indeed fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

First, Auth0 only issues access-tokens, it does not evaluate it for access-control decisions in your API. Your problem is in Spring web-security configuration of your resource-server (the authorization-server being Auth0 is not important).

Second, what you should expect is actually a 403 (forbidden which mean that authentication is valid but access was denied) and not a 401 (unauthorized which means that authentication is missing or invalid).

Have you checked that your `SecurityConfig` is correctly loaded with a breakpoint or log line? It Seams that `@Configuration` is missing and my bet is that your resource-server is actually secured with spring-boot default `SecurityFilterChain` which only applies `anyRequest().authenticated()`.

You could also disable sessions (and CSRF protection). Access could be denied because of CSRF protection which is useless when sessions are disabled and sessions are rarely needed with access-tokens. It would also ease scaling and fault tolerance.

You could have a look at [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) for resource-server configuration and access-control tests.

## Edit: complete sample

```java
package com.c4soft.dumb;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DumbApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DumbApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(path = "/dumb")
    public class AuthController {
        @GetMapping("/public")
        public String getPublic() {
            return "Hello!";
        }

        @GetMapping("/person")
        public String getPersonFromEmail(@RequestParam(name = "email") String email) {
            return email;
        }

        @GetMapping("/name")
        public String getName(Authentication auth) {
            return auth.getName();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig {
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();

            http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().csrf().disable();

            // @formatter:off
            http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/dumb/public").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/dumb/person").hasAuthority("SCOPE_email")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
            // @formatter:on

            http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());
            
            return http.build();
        }

        private CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
            final var configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
            configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
            configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
            configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
            configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));

            final var source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/dumb/**", configuration);

            return source;
        }
    }
}
```

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=https://dev-ch4mpy.eu.auth0.com/
```

Queries with Postman work exactly as expected:

- `http://localhost:8080/dumb/public` is accessible without any authentication
- `http://localhost:8080/dumb/name` return

  - `401` if access token is missing or invalid (wrong issuer, expired, ...)
  - access-token `sub` claim value if access token is valid
- `http://localhost:8080/dumb/person?email=dumb@truc.com` returns

  - `401` if access token is missing or invalid (wrong issuer, expired, ...)
  - `403` if client did not request `email` scope
  - `dumb@truc.com` if access-token is valid and has `email` scope

Comment: This would be more of a comment then an answer. You are correct it should be a 403 not 401 that was a mistype but it is still not throwing the that. It is letting the request through. I think everything is at least getting loaded because if I remove everything then I don't get the 401 when there is no token.

Comment: Also I don't see in the example where you are checking the scope that is the part that isn't working.

Comment: Looks like it is something with the matcher

Comment: And what about the second paragraph? This is very likely the answer: I believe your configuration class is not loaded because of missing annotation

Comment: The samples use authorities mappers to get it from any claim (not only scope) and with any prefix (not only `SCOPE_`)

Comment: I have confirmed that it isn't a problem with the config loading. The SCOPE_ was part of the Auth0 documentation https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/java-spring-security5/01-authorization

Comment: How did you confirm that?

Comment: Because now I can get the 403 when I don't include the url params

Comment: Also I can confirm .requestMatchers("/").permitAll() does work without the 403

Comment: The tutorial you are pointing is valid when you are OK with spring-security default which maps authorities from `scope`. If you want to map it from, lets say `groups` or whatever is better suited for access control, then you'll have to provide an authentication converter as done in my samples and tutorials.

Comment: None of your arguments confirm that you are not using default spring-boot SecurityFilterChain. Do as I wrote: set a breakpoint or log line and then decorate `SecurityConfig` with `@Configuration`

Comment: I have confirmed with a debugger that it is hitting inside the config

Comment: It doesn't seem to be stopping at the validator though for example it doesn't stop here public OAuth2TokenValidatorResult validate(Jwt jwt). So perhaps it is a problem with the JWTDecoder method? Thanks for your help

Comment: And what about the last paragraph (with stateless session-management and disabled CSRF protection)?

Comment: Yes I have sessions turned off and cors configured.

Comment: And CSRF disabled?

Comment: I believe that is what the cors call does

Comment: https://blog.vnaik.com/posts/web-attacks.html

Comment: You'll just need to edit Auth0 issuer property with your own account to try the app I added in the edit but honestly, I can't believe you could not get things working as I already explained every single step (can you read?)